# NSURLProtocol Timing out too fast

Tags: ios, nsurlprotocol

I have observed that some time StopLoading is getting called within a second . Its not giving enough time to serve the request.

Has anyone else has encountered similar behavior before?
IS there any solution to this problem?

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: NSURLProtocol  in an XCode project which is gonna run on iOS7.